# How to include moment Js in Lightning Web Component? I have used the below code

Tags: salesforce, lwc

```
import moment from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/XXX';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

    export default class ProjectActivity extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, moment + '/js/moment.js')
        ]);
        this.loadActivities();
    }
    loadActivities(){
        let eventStartDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `loadActivities` does not wait for moment to actually load.

What you need to do is:

```
connectedCallback(){
    Promise.all([
          loadScript(this, moment + '/js/moment.js')
        ]).then(() => {
          this.loadActivities();
      });
    }
```